# Validity of a Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Probability Density Function Validity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96674/probability-density-function-validity)

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with range $[x_l,\infty)$ and p.d.f.

$f_x(X)\propto x^{-a}$, for $x\in[x_l,\infty)$

for some values $x_l > 0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

After integrating $f(x)$, how can I find the range of values for $a$ that would make $f(x)$ a valid pdf?

Comment: Thanks, Chris for replying to that :) Do you happen to have any hints for me, please? Nikhil, I saw that one, but I couldn't comment on it as I wanted to talk to Dilip. So I thought I could get to talk to him if he commented here.

Comment: For convergence of the integral we need $a>1$. That's the only general condition on $a$. If $f_X(x)=kx^{-a}$, we find that
$\int_{x_l}^\infty kx^{-a}\,dx=\frac{k}{(a-1)x_l^{a-1}}$. For any $a$, $x_l$ there is a unique $k$ such that the integral is (as needed) equal to $1$.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we find the range of values for a? Also, do you have an email/gtalk account we could use to talk more about this, please? Oh wait, so you're saying that the range is basically just (1, infinity)?

Comment: @SorinCioban I replied to your previous query about how to find the range for $a$.  Why didn't you read that instead of posting the same question again?  I am recommending closure of this question.

Comment: Hi Dilip. I'm not the same person as the one that posted in the other thread. I couldn't comment on that one to talk to you so I thought I could get to talk to you by posting the question again. Could we talk privately about the question in any way? Thanks :)

Comment: A [complete solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/96712/15941) to the _other_ identical question has just been posted by David Mitra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be a real number, and let $f_X(x)=kx^{-a}$, where $k>0$.  Since we are dealing with positive quantities, the only thing that we require in order for $f_X(x)$ to be a density function is
$$\int_{x_l}^\infty kx^{-a}\,dx=1.\qquad\qquad(\ast)$$ 
The above integration, like many others that arise in probability, is over an infinite interval, so may fail to exist.

We will show that the above integral converges if $a>1$ and diverges otherwise.

Let
$$I(M)=\int_{x_l}^M kx^{-a}\,dx.$$
By definition, if $\lim_{M\to\infty}I(M)$ exists, the integral in $(\ast)$ converges and has value equal to that limit.

Suppose first that $a>1$. Integrating, we find that 
$$I(M)=\int_{x_l}^M kx^{-a}\,dx=\left.\frac{-k}{(a-1)x^{a-1}}\right|_{x_l}^M$$
Thus 
$$I(M)=\frac{k}{(a-1)x_{x_l}^{a-1}}-\frac{k}{(a-1)M^{a-1}}. \qquad\qquad(\ast\ast)$$
Since $a-1>0$, we can see that $\frac{k}{(a-1)M^{a-1}}\to 0$ as $M\to\infty$. It follows that if $a>1$, then 
$$\int_{x_l}^\infty kx^{-a}\,dx=\frac{k}{(a-1){x_l}^{a-1}}.$$

For *any* $a>1$, and any positive $x_l$, we can find a unique constant of proportionality $k$ such that 
$$\frac{k}{(a-1){x_l}^{a-1}}=1.$$
Just take $k=(a-1)x_l^{a-1}$. So everything is fine if $a>1$.

We complete the analysis by showing that if $a \le 1$, then our integral **does not** converge. There are two somewhat different cases, $a=1$ and $a<1$. 
Suppose first that $a=1$. Then 
$$I(M)=\int_{x_l}^M kx^{-1}\,dx=\left.k\ln x\right|_{x_l}^M=k\ln M-k\ln x_l.$$ 
As $M\to\infty$, $\ln M\to\infty$, so $I(M)$ does not have a finite limit, and therefore $\int_{x_l}^\infty kx^{-1}\,dx$ does not exist.

Finally, we deal with $a<1$.  In this case, 
$$I(M)=\frac{kM^{1-a}}{1-a}-\frac{kx_l^{1-a}}{1-a}.$$
As $M\to\infty$, $I(M)\to\infty$, so the integral from $x_l$ to $\infty$ diverges (does not have a finite value).

Comment: You managed to write a lot without mentioning that this is called the Pareto distribution, after Vilfredo Pareto.

Comment: I thought the OP's issue was a calculus one. So I wanted to do those details only. Didn't know his first name was Vilfredo.

Comment: I don't think it's generally a good idea to restrict answers to what the OP explicitly asks about.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Agreed! I usually add a "Comment" at the end of most answers, pushing a bit beyond the actual question. Didn't this time.

Answer (score 0):

Say you've found
$$
\int_{x_\ell}^\infty x^{-a}\;dx.
$$

This is a valid pdf if the integral is finite; it is not a valid pdf if the integral is $\infty$.

The family of distributions we're dealing with here are called the Pareto distributions, after the Italian economist Vilfredo Pareto (1848--1923).  It arises from Pareto's way of modeling the distribution of incomes.  Pareto proposed that
$$
\log N = A - a\log x
$$
where $N$ is the number of people whose incomes are more than $x$.  A bit of trivial algebra shows how the density arises from what Pareto proposed, but Pareto neglected to think about $x_\ell$.